# Tron theme for gnome-session-fallback

Tags: themes, gnome-session

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and I installed gnome-session-fallback (classic gnome). I really want the tron theme, but there is a certain theme that I have to download for my desktop environment. Can you guys help me out? I am really lost with what I am supposed to download and also installing the theme. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the theme [from](http://half-left.deviantart.com/art/GNOME-Shell-Tron-Legacy-208220836), and install it via gnome-tweak-tool. Detailed descriptions are present in the link.

Comment: I thought it worked on the current version of gnome and not gnome fallback. Thanks